# How do I start emacs in a console window when emacs -nw doesn't work?

Tags: windows, emacs, console

I have installed cygwin and msys2 on Windows 10 to have a console-mode emacs installation.

When I start emacs from either console with

```
emacs
```

I just get the standard windows GUI I installed cygwin to avoid.

When I start emacs from either console with

```
emacs -nw
```

I get

```
emacs: standard input is not a tty
```

[image: Example console output]

How do I get emacs to begin as a console session?

I have tried running mintty first and starting emacs inside it, and I get the same thing.